# Return statement in case of exception

Tags: java, exception, methods, return, try-catch

What is the correct way of using `return` in the following method?

```
public Image getImage() {
    try {
        Image img = ImageIO.read(new File(URL));
        return img;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

IDE asks me to return something at the end. But I don't know what I'm supposed to return.

Comment: If you cannot return anything useful, either dont catch, rethrow or throw a `RuntimeException` or `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @luk2302 and in some cases it may make sense to return an `Optional<Image>`

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answers!

Comment: For the record : I added another important option to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is: depends on your requirements. Options are:

If the caller of this method could deal with a null answer, return null from the catch block. Alternatively, you could return a "special" pre-defined image object in that case. Might be a slightly better way - as returning null is always the first step to cause Nullpointerexceptions elsewhere.

Or, you catch and rethrow some unchecked exception. Or you don't catch at all and you add "throws IoException" to the signature of the method.

When you are using Java 8, the simple solution is to use the new class Optional.

Answer (score 4):

If your method catches the exception and doesn't throw anything, it must return some default value (perhaps null) after the try-catch block.

I think you shouldn't catch the exception. This way you only return a value if the `ImageIO.read` operation doesn't throw an exception. Of course you'll have to declare that your method `throws IOException`, since that's a checked exception.

This will force the caller of your method to handle `IOException` (or let its own caller handle it).